# Is this probability related to the normal distribution correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ e $Y=a X+b$ with cdf's $F_{X}=\Phi$ e $F_{Y}$ respectively.

Now let $a \neq 0$, it seems immidiate to me that
$$F_{Y}(x)=P(aX +b\leq x)=P\left (X \leq \frac{x-b}{a}\right )=\Phi\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)$$
$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

While in an exercise that gave my professor at an exam this answer was given as false (it was a true/false). Is it true or am I missing something?

Comment: If you divide an inequality by a negative number the inequality sign gets reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not correct.  What happens if $a$ is negative?

Comment: Ah right!! Thanks, I'm too tired now 